# Rolling a die 1000 times. Estimate the probability $ℙ( \prod^{1000}_{n=1} X_n ≤ z^{1000})$ for real $1 < z < 6$

Tags: probability, statistics

Rolling a die 1000 times, denoting the outcome of roll by $X_n$.

Estimate the probability  $ℙ( \displaystyle\prod^{1000}_{n=1} X_n ≤ z^{1000})$

for real $1 < z < 6$

I've taken the natural log of both sides to change the product into a sum and I've subtracted $1000*[ln(X_n)]$ and divided by $\sqrt{1000*Var(ln(X_n))}$ on both sides so that it has standard normal distribution.

I was going to use the Central Limit Theorem but as $z$ is an unknown real I think the Law of Large Numbers would be more useful but I am unsure how to go about it.

I know that with a low $z$ the value will be closer to $0$ and a high $z$ it will be closer to $1$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks as if $3^{1000}$ may be interesting

Comment: @qwefgh I think that the answer in terms of CDF of standard normal law $\Phi(x)$ will be the best.

Comment: The geometric mean of $1,2,3,4,5,6$ is $\sqrt[6]{6!} = \sqrt[6]{720} \approx 2.993795$. The Law of Large Numbers tells you that the expected value of the log of the product is probably close to $1000$ times the log of this.  So the probability of the product being less than or equal to $z^{1000}$ will be close to $0$ for $z$ substantially less than  $2.993795$ (for $z=1$ it is $\frac{1}{6^{1000}}$) and will be close to $1$ for $z$ substantially more than $2.993795$.  But to get a better estimate when $z$ is close to $2.993795$, the normal approximation looks as if it is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost done. We have
\begin{align}
\Pr\left(\prod_{n=1}^{1000}X_n \leq z^{1000}\right) &= \Pr\left(\sum_{n=1}^{1000}\ln(X_n) \leq 1000\ln (z)\right) \\
&=\Pr\left(\frac{\left(\sum_{n=1}^{1000}\ln X_n - 1000\cdot\mathsf{E}(\ln X_1)\right)}{\sqrt{1000\cdot \mathsf{var}(\ln X_1)}}\leq \frac{\sqrt{1000}\cdot(\ln z - \mathsf{E}(\ln X_1))}{\sqrt{\mathsf{var}(\ln X_1)}}\right) \\
&\approx \Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt{1000}\cdot(\ln z - \mathsf{E}(\ln X_1))}{\sqrt{\mathsf{var}(\ln X_1)}}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: I originally did this, but how would you show for any real, other than plugging in values to z? Is there a way to estimate it with the LLN?

Comment: @qwefgh For different $z$, the probability varies. Therefore, the probability must be a function of $z$.

Comment: @qwefgh LLN is not a way to estimate probabilities. If you mean Chebyshev's inequality than you can get only a pair of inequalities in different directions: for $z> E\ln X_1$ this will be an estimate from below, and for $z<E\ln X_1$ from above. And these estimates are very imprecise.